# Creating a new Angular project on Mac with Visual Studio

Tags: angular, macos, visual-studio-community

I'm currently going through a `https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103` on setting up Spa apps with Visual Studio on Mac (macOS Sierra, Visual Studio Community 2017).

I've successfully installed angular core, and am currently trying to create a new project based off of one of the installed templates.

I can see two angular templates when I run `sudo dotnet new -l`:

`MVC ASP.NET Core with Angular      angular         [C#]          Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with Angular          angular         [C#]          Web/MVC/SPA`

When running `sudo dotnet new angular`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to determine the desired template from the input template name: angular.
The following templates partially match the input. Be more specific with the template name and/or language.

Templates                          Short Name      Language      Tags       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
MVC ASP.NET Core with Angular      angular         [C#]          Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with Angular          angular         [C#]          Web/MVC/SPA


Examples:
    dotnet new angular
    dotnet new angular
    dotnet new --help
```

Is there something in the command I'm missing? Is something with Visual Studio / dotnet configured incorrectly?

Comment: How did you install the templates?, the way to do it is `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`

Comment: @Hackerman Yup! That's exactly what I did, actually.

Comment: We can test one thing....what am I thinking is that the default installation of VS 2017 in your MAC, already install the angular template...what you can do is run `dotnet new -u angular`...then check that both templates are gone....then install again using the `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`

Comment: Hmm - got `Could not find something to uninstall called 'angular'. @Hackerman

Comment: Run this command `dotnet new --debug:reinit ` and check the template list

Comment: @Hackerman this solved my issue. Could you suggest where can one learn more on the dotnet commands?

Comment: You can always check the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet

Answer (score 6):

To install the Single Page Application (SPA) templates, run the following command:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

[image]

Now create any SPA ...

```
dotnet new angular -o ngApp
cd .\ngApp\
npm install
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

Comment: Please leave @PaulRoub's edit be, Muhammad - it was a good edit. We discourage salutations, greetings, sign-offs and signatures here, and if such edits become the subject of an edit war, a moderator will tend to prefer the version without them.

Answer (score 2):

With .netcore 2.1

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
cd my-new-app
```

Now on 2.1 the package.json is inside client app

```
    cd ClientApp
    npm install
    dotnet restore
    dotnet run
```