# System Aggregation Exception : Failed to start Node Process

Tags: angular, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I, have create a angular app in mac os using vs2017 and followed the sample form [Creating a new Angular project on Mac with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831899/creating-a-new-angular-project-on-mac-with-visual-studio) with docker support for three project. Since the other project are Web API. Since the other project are successfully running on the docker. However only the angular app is not running and it throw an error as below

```
System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.\n\n[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.\n    Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\n    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.\n\n[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)" ---> System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}: "Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.\n\n[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.\n    Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\n    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.\n\n[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause." ---> System.Exception {System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception}: "No such file or directory"
  at at System.Diagnostics.Process.ResolvePath(String filename)\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance..ctor(String entryPointScript, String projectPath, String[] watchFileExtensions, String commandLineArguments, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, ILogger nodeOutputLogger, IDictionary`2 environmentVars, Int32 invocationTimeoutMilliseconds, Boolean launchWithDebugging, Int32 debuggingPort)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance..ctor(NodeServicesOptions options, Int32 port)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeServicesOptionsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<UseHttpHosting>b__0()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.CreateNewNodeInstance()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.GetOrCreateCurrentNodeInstance()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.NodeServicesImpl.<InvokeExportWithPossibleRetryAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)\n   at WebApp.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRental/WebApp/Startup.cs:line 34\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()\n   at WebApp.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRental/WebApp/Program.cs:line 21\n   at WebApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRental/WebApp/Program.cs:17
```

[image: error is start.cs]

[image: Inner Exception]

[image: docker file]

Tried to solve the error from this link https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/707 but no result.

[image: node path]

Comment: Is node available on that path as shown in the error message?

Comment: yes the node is available on that path please  find the screen shot

Comment: Does it work if you run the Angular project from the command line using `dotnet path/to/your/assembly.dll`?

Comment: yes it work when I run the command - "dotnet run"

Comment: What is the full path to node on your machine? VS Mac has a different PATH when compared to running dotnet from the command line. Just wondering if that is the problem here, or something else.

Comment: So you are running the angular project on docker? Does the docker container not have node installed?

Comment: Yes I, am running angular project on docker. I don't know the node is install in it or not. Can you please let me know the steps to install node on docker

Comment: Not able to solve the error.  here is the git link can you please let me know how can I solve this.https://github.com/anandjaisy/testapplication

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from this link and it worked.

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1534#issuecomment-366605094

**modified the angular app docker file**

**change this line**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
```

**to**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS base
```

**Updated Docker file**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRental.sln ./
COPY WebApp/WebApp.csproj WebApp/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApp
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```